# VBA to Set All Controls in All Forms

Tags: forms, properties, controls

Periodically, my database gets slow and I have to create a new database and import all my forms, etc. into the new database. For some reason, all my form control settings (Access Theme, etc.) gets lost and I have to manually go through every control on every form to reset it to the way I like it.

My question is:

1. Is there a way to keep all my form control properties and settings when I import them into the new database?
2. If not, how would I use VBA to do this for me automatically... looping through all the controls on all my forms to set all the properties to the way I like it? And, even more specific, I have a Sample Form with one of each control with all the properties set the way I want. So, how could I open this Sample Form and read each control's properties to copy to all the same controls on all my forms?

Answer (score 0):

Performing a "Compact & Repair Database" action under the file tab will speed up your slow database. So you will not have to export and create a new instance of the database.

[Microsoft does a good job of explaining](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/compact-and-repair-a-database-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2)

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I Compact and Repair all the time.

I found the answer to my question: When I create a new database and import the forms from my old, slow, database, Access asks if I want to import the Themes along with the forms and, when I check this box, it copies all the forms' formatting, colors, etc. I think you have to click the Advanced button (or something like that) to see this option when you're in the Forms tab.